# Sql- ordering based on two columns in a table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, collections

consider a database having

```
checkID record_number   data    Order_number
a                0        1        2
a                1        2        0
a                2        3        1
a                3        4        3
```

Find a query which fetches the records  according to Order_number column i.e.procedure should return  data :

```
having record _number 2 then
having record _number 0 then
having record _number 1 then
having record _number 3
```

Is there any join or other query for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE WHEN record_number = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, record_number;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a932b/1)

This will give you your data in the following order:

```
| CHECKID | RECORD_NUMBER | DATA | ORDER_NUMBER |
-------------------------------------------------
|       a |             2 |    3 |            1 |
|       a |             0 |    1 |            2 |
|       a |             1 |    2 |            0 |
|       a |             3 |    4 |            3 |
```

Comment: What do you use formatting your data results? As you can [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14977123/447156), I failed on this :).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I want to generalise it.. so that ordering can happen dynamically.. the first column would be the same(checkID), it is the primary key. and want to generalise it for N number of results.

Comment: @Ankit - So for n number of results there should be n case ordering. Right?? `having record _number 2 then` , ... tell n?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    YourTable
order by
        case record_number
        when 2 then 1
        when 0 then 2
        when 1 then 3
        when 3 then 4
        end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[CASE WHEN](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html)** on this situation.;

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl
ORDER BY CASE record_number
              WHEN 2 THEN 1
              WHEN 0 THEN 2
              WHEN 1 THEN 3
              WHEN 3 THEN 4
              END
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b289/1)**.

```
| CHECKID | RECORD_NUMBER | DATA | ORDER_NUMBER |
-------------------------------------------------
|       a |             2 |    3 |            1 |
|       a |             0 |    1 |            2 |
|       a |             1 |    2 |            0 |
|       a |             3 |    4 |            3 |
```

Comment: Beside the `Run SQL` button, there is a small arrow, press it and choose `Markdown Output`.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to create additional table for sorting checks, like this:

```
record_number   sort_seq
     2              1
     0              2
     1              3
     3              4
```

then join it with your table

```
select c.* 
from check as c 
     join sortSeq as s on c.record_number=s.record_number 
order by s.sort_seq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY Order_number
```